# How to set a range for a textfield length with jquery inputmask plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, validation

I need to set a mask that allow the user to enter at least 5 digits and optionally more than five but less than 10.

This is what I actually have:

$('#codeNumber').inputmask('99999[999999]');

But it doesn't work.

[Here](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) you can find the plugin's specification. There you can find that optional masks can be set between square brackets but doesn't seem to work.

Do you know how can achieve this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for...

`$('#codeNumber').inputmask("mask", {"mask": "99999[99999]"});​`

Comment: Thanks Timothy for your answer, but it doesn't work and I still don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Download jquery files and add in your project then write this code or follow the article